# rotating the depth image about lowest row in 3D

Tags: ros, image, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a depth image which I want to rotated about a point to project the points in another plane which is at an angle t from the plane about the col axis
so,
[r2 c2]' = [ct st ; -st ct] [r c]'
Should give me a rotation about angle t, with the column axis of the lowest row (479th row) as the pivot.
Lets think about it as seeing the optical plane from one side and seeing only the row axis
Now, the problem is that I can't have the same depth values once I rotate the image. I don't know how the depth values would change.
Can someone help me figure this out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55839/rotating-the-depth-image-about-lowest-row-in-3d/) by [navderm](https://answers.ros.org/users/984/navderm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you could project the depth values to 3D and then project to the new plane?

---

Originally posted by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) with karma: 396 on 2013-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0